# NLP text transformation Changing subject

Tags: nlp

I'm new to the world of NLP but would like to know if there's currently any easy way (using a service or OSS etc) of changing the subject of a bulk of text using NLP where the original subject is known (and preferably if such a method is available in multiple languages?) (Equivalent to the method sentences().toPastTense() detailed / available here: https://nlp-compromise.github.io )

Lets say that the original text is written about "you", and you know that to always be the case, but you want to automatically generate a version of the text that would be changed to be about "your brother"

**(quite nonsensical) example:**

> "You should go down the hall, as you reach the corner you are done."

Would turn into

> "Your brother should go down the hall, as he reaches the corner he is
>   done."

As far as I understand, this type of text transformation is reliant on lemmatisation (as demonstrated in this post https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-natural-language-processing-for-text-df845750fb63), but as I've been researching text transformation methods I haven't seen any methods pertaining to the subject of sentences?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any off hand, but it can certainly be done. For example, using [TextBlob](https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html) you could try to come up with a function using parts-of-speech. Obviously you'd need more than this little snippet here, like a function that checks subject/verb agreement, but it's an example of an approach, and hopefully it's food for thought.

```py
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob.taggers import NLTKTagger
from textblob import Word

def lil_subj_replacer(phrase,input_subj,input_prp):
    nltk_tagger = NLTKTagger()
    blob = TextBlob(phrase,pos_tagger=nltk_tagger)
    subject = True
    for i,keyval in enumerate(blob.pos_tags):
        key = keyval[0]
        value = keyval[1]
        if (value == 'PRP'):
            if subject:
                blob.words[i] = input_subj
                subject = False
            else:
                blob.words[i] = input_prp

            blob.words[i+1] = Word(blob.words[i+1]).lemmatize('v')
    return ' '.join(blob.words)

my_phrase = 'You should go down the hall, as you reach the corner you are done.'
print(my_phrase)
print(lil_subj_replacer(phrase=my_phrase,input_subj='Your brother',input_prp='he'))
```

original: `You should go down the hall, as you reach the corner you are done.`

no lemmatize: `Your brother should go down the hall as he reach the corner he are done`

lemmatized verbs: `Your brother should go down the hall as he reach the corner he be done`

edit: added example with lemmaz, since you mentioned it.